# Way to get AutoComplete working in a DataGridViewComboBoxColumn?

Tags: c#, autocomplete

I've already successfully gotten autocomplete working in a regular combo box. I used the leave event to set the selection to null if the user types in something that isn't in the list.

Now, I want to do this in a DataGridViewComboBoxColumn. However, the usual properties like AutoCompleteMode and AutoCompleteSource are missing. I hear there's a way get this done using casting somehow but I can't read the VB language instructions too well. Ideally I want to make a new derived class so I can easily use this thing over and over.

The other problem is I need to know what event to intercept in order to reset the combobox to its old value or null if the item isn't in the list.

Help would be appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get this feature by implementing the EditingControlShowing event of the grid.
Essentially when you edit a combobox column, the editing control is a combobox
So by casting you can setup the properties for Autocomplete

```
void grdPerformanceScenario_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Control is ComboBox)
        {
            (e.Control as ComboBox).AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest;
            (e.Control as ComboBox).AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.ListItems;
        }
    }
```

Comment: yeah, I've since figured out how to import my own controls into the datagridview. I prefer to make my own column classes for the autocomplete enabled boxes though, so I can insert the properties it needs in the column setup part of the dgv instead of handling this event over and over.

Answer (score 0):

There is a `AutoComplete` for `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn`.

For example:

```
DataGridViewComboBoxColumn comboBox = DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
combobox.AutoComplete = true;
```